# ehCache setTimeToLive in milliseconds

Tags: ehcache

I want to set "time to live" in cache for 500 msecs.
Is there a method in ehCache which will allow to set time in msecs?

*public void setTimeToLive(int timeToLiveSeconds)
Allows to set time in lowest possible of 1 sec == 1000 msec*

Regards,
Amber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Ehcache 2.x time to live and time to idle do not have a more precise granularity.

[JSR-107](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr107/index.html) supports duration with milliseconds precision. The [ehcache-jcache](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache-jcache) wrapper will round expiry to the second.

[Ehcache 3](https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3) will support milliseconds granularity.